# iOS constraints errors in simulator only

Tags: ios, xcode

I have designed my iOS app UI using Xcode Storyboard, everything looks fine now errors, no alerts.

When I run my app in the simulator, I get a list of `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`. This list is very ambiguous.

```
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b617600 UIButton:0x7b6112f0.width == UIButton:0x7b6112f0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7abd20 UIButton:0x7b7a3180.centerY == UIButton:0x7b79d0f0.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7abd50 UIButton:0x7b7a3180.width == UIButton:0x7b6112f0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7abd80 UIButton:0x7b7a3180.height == UIButton:0x7b6112f0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7abdb0 UIButton:0x7b7a3180.centerX == UIButton:0x7b770ec0.centerX>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7abde0 V:[UIButton:0x7b7a3180]-(2)-[UIButton:0x7b770ec0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7abe30 H:|-(0)-[UIButton:0x7b770ec0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b7abbf0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7abe60 UIButton:0x7b79d0f0.centerY == UIButton:0x7b78ff40.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7abec0 H:[UIButton:0x7b7a3180]-(NSSpace(8))-[UIButton:0x7b79d0f0](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7abf20 UIButton:0x7b79d0f0.width == UIButton:0x7b6112f0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7abf50 UIButton:0x7b6112f0.height == UIButton:0x7b770ec0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7abf80 UIButton:0x7b6112f0.height == UIButton:0x7b78ff40.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7abfb0 UIButton:0x7b6112f0.centerY == UIButton:0x7b770ec0.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7abfe0 UIButton:0x7b6112f0.width == UIButton:0x7b78ff40.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7ac010 UIButton:0x7b6112f0.width == UIButton:0x7b770ec0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7ac040 V:|-(2)-[UIButton:0x7b78ff40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b7abbf0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7ac070 H:[UIButton:0x7b79d0f0]-(NSSpace(8))-[UIButton:0x7b78ff40](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7ac0a0 H:[UIButton:0x7b78ff40]-(0)-|(LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b7abbf0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7ac0d0 UIButton:0x7b60d210.height == UIButton:0x7b6112f0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7ac100 UIButton:0x7b60d210.centerY == UIButton:0x7b6112f0.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7ac130 UIButton:0x7b60d210.bottom == UIView:0x7b7abbf0.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7ac390 V:[UIView:0x7b7abb60(<=190)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7ac3c0 H:[UIView:0x7b7abbf0]-(4)-|(LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b7abb60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7ac420 UIView:0x7b7abb60.centerX == UIView:0x7b7abbf0.centerX>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7ac450 V:[UIView:0x7b7abbf0]-(>=2)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b7abb60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7ac4b0 UIView:0x7b7abb60.centerY == UIView:0x7b7abbf0.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7bce60 H:[UIView:0x7b7abb60]-(0)-|(LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b7a9640 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7bce90 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7b7abb60](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b7a9640 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7bfa9e30 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x7b7a9640(320)]>"
```

Which button is this: `UIButton:0x7b6112f0`?

Which constraint is this: `NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b7bce90`?

In Xcode `Identity inspector` I found a Label field, I labeled all my buttons. But when run in simulator, these labels are not of any benefits.

How can I identify objects from this output?

Comment: i think you are not setting proper constraints. Check again  the constraints that you have added.

Comment: If you want to know which `UIButton` is, you can press **Pause** on Debugger and you can digit: `expr [(UIButton *)hexCode setSomeProperty: someValue]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no warnings/conflicts shown in IB, maybe it was due to the `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint`. `AutoresizingMask` is something primarily used before `AutoLayout` was introduced. Get rid of it and try again.

Find the `UIView` object of the last line of your list and apply:

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:):

> Because the autoresizing mask naturally gives rise to constraints that fully specify a view’s position, any view that you wish to apply more flexible constraints to must be set to ignore its autoresizing mask using this method. You should call this method yourself for programmatically created views. Views created using a tool that allows setting constraints should have this set already.

Comment: So I understand that autoresizing is already disabled? `Views created using a tool that allows setting constraints should have this set already.` However, in the UI builder I see that all views have `Autoresizing views` checked? Do I uncheck it? or this is something else?

Comment: The last line of the your list shows that there is an `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` installed, for whatever reason.

Comment: I believe you have to disable it by setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` programmatically, as I answered.

Answer (score 3):

You have added too much constraint and duplicate that needed. You should avoid to add duplicate constraints.

Comment: First, this is a misleading link. Second, I have too much objects.

Comment: I am trying to add 6 buttons with equal sizes, 3 in the top, and 3 in the bottom. all of them are centered in the screen. Can you help do it in less constraint?

Comment: Make all 6 buttons equally width and equally height using Editer -->Pin . And align all button to verically or horizontally (as you want)  center using constraint. You don't need to add  more contraints.